# How to use themes with gtk+ in windows

Tags: c, themes, mingw, gtk

I am trying to learn gtk+. I use windows.
By default gtk+ gives a look of Windows 98/2000.

But on linux there are different themes available.
I have downloaded the aurora theme engine and theme. I have also successfully complied it on windows. But don't know how to use it.

I am using Mingw/MSYS.

Comment: I think themes are a desktop-environment thing, not something you can apply to an arbitrary application.

Comment: http://live.learnfree.eu/screenshots 
Check out this page. This application has different looks although it uses gtk+

Comment: It looks to me to be using the system default. If you use standard controls, you'll get standard theming.

Comment: found it
http://sourceforge.net/userapps/mediawiki/alex-sh/index.php?title=Main_Page
Gtk+ Preference tool can do this